# deviceorientation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying some code with the deviceorientation listener and it's not working as I would expect. I've tried a couple different methods (shown below) and both work fine when manually changing Chrome's Debugger Sensors, however, I can't get it to work on any mobile device automatically.

I'm using this site as a reference and demo:

-https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html

-https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-device-orientation-api--cms-21067

The demo above is working great on my phone, but when I try to implement the same code into what I'm working on, nothing happens.

```
export class AppComponent {
    absolute: boolean = false;
    alpha: number = 0;
    beta: number = 0;
    gamma: number = 0;
    private orientation$ = fromEvent(window, 'deviceorientation');

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Method 1
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (e) => console.log(e));

    // Method 2
        this.orientation$.subscribe((res: any) => console.log(res));
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using Chrome on your phone? If you don't host your test page on a secure (`https://`) URL, Chrome won't provide orientation.

Comment: Wow, that works, I didn't realize that was a thing. Do you have a source? I'd be curious to read up a little more on it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As luck would have it I was just playing with that stuff last week, and I stumbled across mention of it somewhere; maybe CanIUse or something like that. It's a fairly recent change to Chrome.

Comment: It says in the spec that it fires only for secure contexts. https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#security-and-privacy

Comment: @Reactgular well for whatever reason mobile Firefox does fire the events on insecure pages, so that's how I stumbled onto the issue (or lack of an issue, I guess).

Comment: My understanding is that `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` will be *undefined* if the browser does not support it or the context is insecure.